# React Jest - TypeError: (0 , _[....]) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm trying to create unit tests with Jest for a React application and unfortunelly getting errors after importing any component into my tests. The error appears on every function that I have.
The application is created with Create React App and this problem repeats on every function that I have on my project.

**index.js**

```
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Settings from './AppEnvironment';
import intl from 'react-intl-universal';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import { stores } from '~/stores';
import { HashRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './assets/stylesheets/styles.scss';
import App from './App';
import ReactBreakpoints from 'react-breakpoints';
import { breakpoints } from '~/utils/BreakPoints';
import AppProvider from './hooks';
import { initialize } from '@TruckPad/truckpad-analytics';
import { initializeGTM, initializeBlip } from '~/services/external';
import { resetLogin } from './utils/Utils';

initialize([Settings.gtag, Settings.utag]);

initializeGTM();
initializeBlip(
  'YXRoZW5hcm91dGVyOjIxN2U2ODdlLTk3MTUtNDE0NC04ZjJiLTNkNTZhNmQ1MGY1NQ==',
  Settings.environment === 'production',
);

const locales = {
  'pt-BR': require('./locales/pt-BR.json'),
  'en-US': require('./locales/en-US.json'),
};
const currentLocale = locales[navigator.language] ? navigator.language : 'pt-BR';

intl.init({
  currentLocale,
  locales,
});

console.log('Environment: ' + Settings.environment);
console.log('Version: ' + Settings.version);
resetLogin();
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider {...stores}>
    <AppProvider>
      <ReactBreakpoints breakpoints={breakpoints}>
        <Router baseline="/">
          <App />
        </Router>
      </ReactBreakpoints>
    </AppProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**Jest config on package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "~/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/",
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
```

**Error when running yarn test**

```
 FAIL  src/pages/Shipments/List/ShipmentsList.spec.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , _Utils.generateUUID) is not a function

      283 | export const stoppingPointEmpty = {
      284 |   action: '',
    > 285 |   key: generateUUID(),
          |        ^
      286 |   address: {
      287 |     street_name: '',
      288 |     street_number: '',

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Commons.js:285:8)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/stores/VehicleStore.js:5:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/utils/GenericClass.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.js:14:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/index.js:12:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/Shipments/List/ShipmentsList.js:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/Shipments/List/ShipmentsList.spec.js:2:1)
```

This function (generateUUID) and every other function with **export const** is giving me the same errors.

Anyone here ever have the same problem? I think probably is an babel config or something like that.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm having the similar problem.

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 2):

I had the same weird issue…
In my case I had a file called `feature.js` just next to the real file I wanted to import `feature.ts`.

The .js file probably appeared when I ran tsc by mistake (or webstorm did it for me…)

In my understanding, jest tried to import the `.js` file instead of the `.ts` one

Removing `feature.js` fixed the problem. PS: I am running TS 4.5.